# VSCODE inserting spaces via format on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCODE seems to be inserting spaces everywhere in my html code. I checked the settings and it's the following which is causing it:     `"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Example:

[image]

How do I configure this to stop inserting spaces?

Comment: Hi Even I am having the same problem. Did you find a resolution for it. For me it is inserting space after and before angle brackets too.

Comment: is it possible that you have any supernumerary " in your code?
In my case thats was the problem.

Answer (score 15):

I have the following set :

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.insertSpaces": false
```

Now it is not inserting spaces. Hope it helps

Answer (score 12):

Mine was caused by an extension JS/ CSS formatter, after i uninstalled and restart vscode works great.
After spending hours wondering why my django static links are broken smh

Comment: Solved my issue!

Comment: Solved the issue for me as well. In my case was the "Prettier - Code formatter" extension.

Answer (score 3):

When saving, Visual Studio inserted a lot of spaces. This happened after an update of Visual Studio. This problem was because of an extension called `Bracket Pair Colorizer`. What I did was, uninstall and reinstall, and that solved the problem. I suggest to check all your extensions. It could be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the option of HTML formatting and no more space when saving files.

```
Settings > Extensions > HTML > Format: Enable

Enable/disable default HTML formatter.
```

Answer (score 1):

Now vscode has option
`"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable"`

It will not reformat whole file on save, modified content will be formatted (given source control is present)

Answer (score 0):

What was the case with me is that I had the option `Editor: Format on save mode` to be set to `file`, this in combination with format on save would mean VS Code will try to format the entire file, resulting in spaces as defined in the formatter.
Change this to be `modifictions`, and VS Code will only save the lines you have made changes in.