# How to prevent vscode saving files add space after question mark?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I save the JS file, VScode automatically adding a space after saving. I have tried to change the VScode setting 'format file' to null but it still not work.

original:

```
console.log(users[0] ?.name ?? 'No name property');
```

after saving the code:

```
console.log(users[0] ? .name ? ? 'No name property');
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is your jsconfig set up to recognize nullish operators?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Well, I'm not sure, it still not work after I delete my setting files to the default setting, then I deleted all my extension files, it works. It must be wrong in some extension configs. It's really wired that even I turned off the "formatOnSave", change the Editor "defaultFormatter" to null and  unload Prettier and Beautify, it still format my file after saving.

Answer (score 0):

I found this possible solution from a quick search here. Hope it corrects your issue.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.insertSpaces": false
```

original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024696/11501774

Comment: Thank you! I tried this before, it doesn't help.